# How do I prevent @State objects from being reset when the view temporarily disappears?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have state objects which are set from a file picker on one of my three views, let's say on `View1`.

```
@State private var fileName : String = ""
@State private var listFileURLs = [URL]()
@State private var selectedFileIndex = 0
```

When I switch over to another view and return, the state objects appear to be reset. The views are switched by an if-else clause based on button states

```
if (showFirstView) {
    View1()
} else if (showSecondView) {
    View2()
}
```

I tried turning the variables static,

```
@State static private var fileName : String = ""
@State static private var listFileURLs = [URL]()
@State static private var selectedFileIndex = 0
```

But that strangely resulted in these variables not being updated when I launched the file picker.

I can't move these variables to the super View, because they are set by controls in View1.
How should I proceed?

Comment: What do you mean by "because they are set by controls in View1"? Why does that make you unable to move the states to the superview?

Comment: declare  state var filename: String  instead of  static, private var filename : String = ""

Comment: Move the state up to the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is that you create a new View every time `showFirstView` is changed.

You can move your `@State` var from child view to parent view like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingFirstView = false
    @State private var state1 = "text"
    @State private var state2 = "text2"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if showingFirstView {
                View1(state1: $state1)
            } else {
                View2(state2: $state2)
            }
            Button("Switch view") {
                showingFirstView.toggle()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    @Binding var state1: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $state1)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    @Binding var state2: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $state2)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I thought state variables controlled by View1 couldn't be moved up to its Superview